# Possible to globally change .NET Minimal API to respond with XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I see in this summary how to properly return XML or HTML for a single endpoint using IResult and IResultExtensions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#customizing-results

What if I want to do this for all routes or for a route group and for error responses?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#removing-the-json-or-xml-formatter

Comment: That's Web API not Minimal APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [Wildcard and catch all routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/route-handlers?view=aspnetcore-7.0#wildcard-and-catch-all-routes) to map different partterns to one handler

Try with generic custom result that could be applied to different handler

```
public class CusResult<T> : IResult
{
    private static readonly XmlSerializer Serializer = new(typeof(T));
    private readonly T _result;

    public CusResult(T result)
    {
        _result = result;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        //modify logical here
        if (httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Contains("html"))
        {
            httpContext.Response.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(_result?.ToString() ?? "");
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(_result?.ToString() ?? "");
        }
        var headeraccept = httpContext.Request.Headers["Accept"].ToString();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(headeraccept))
        {
            if (headeraccept == "application/xml")
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(ms, _result);
                ms.Position = 0;
                httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
                await ms.CopyToAsync(httpContext.Response.Body);
            }
            if (headeraccept == "application/json")
            {
                System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(ms, _result);
                ms.Position = 0;
                httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                await ms.CopyToAsync(httpContext.Response.Body);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in Minimal Api:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapGet("/Person", () => {
    var person=new Person() { FirstName="Andrew",LastName="Lock"};
    return new CusResult<Person>(person);
});    

app.MapGet("/Product", () =>
{
    var product = new Product() { ProductName = "Product", Label = "Label" };
    return new CusResult<Product>(product);
});    

app.MapGet("/html", () => { return new CusResult<string>(@$"<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head><title>miniHTML</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>The time on the server is {DateTime.Now:O}</p>
    </body>
</html>");
});
app.Run();
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Ahh - wildcards. That was the hint I needed.

Comment: A follow-up question about pros and cons of IResult vs Results.Text():
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589533/iresult-vs-results-text-for-returning-other-content-types