# IResult vs Results.Text for returning other content types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Yesterday I asked a question about generically returning different content types. I got the hint to use wildcards

[Possible to globally change .NET Minimal API to respond with XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76585657/possible-to-globally-change-net-minimal-api-to-respond-with-xml/76587915)

And while waiting for feedback, I had played with the extension signatures of Results.Text().

For example

```
public static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IResult Text (ReadOnlySpan<byte> utf8Content, string? contentType = default, int? statusCode = default);
```

Combining with the wildcard route hint:

```
app.MapGet("/html/{*rest}", () => {
    (string content, int statusCode) = GetHtmlResults(rest);
    return Results.Text(content:content, contentType:"text/html", contentEncoding:Encoding.UTF8, statusCode: statusCode);
});
```

or even

```
app.MapGet("/generic/{*rest}", (HttpContext httpContext) => {
    (string content, int statusCode, string contentType) = GetGenericResults(httpContext,rest);
    return Results.Text(content:content, contentType:contentType, contentEncoding:Encoding.UTF8, statusCode: statusCode);
});
```

Seems more direct and less verbose than using a class derived from IResult.
Is IResult just a more structured way of doing the same? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: ... and more memory hungry ... deriving from IResult allows to serialize directly to output stream ... here you are allocating whole string to send it ... also opinion based question - which are off-topic

Comment: Could you point me to an example of that? All the examples that I see are serializing to a memory stream, and then optimizing that.
https://andrewlock.net/returning-xml-from-minimal-apis-in-dotnet-6/

Comment: `HttpContext.Response.Body` is a stream ....

Comment: Got it. Using Response.Text I can't avoid the overhead of a content string.

Comment: The way to return XML is to set the contentType to `application/xml` then it's automatically formatted to XML as long as you have the formatter in place (that's the default). You can do this either using the above code or on `Result` returning functions

Comment: I can stream directly to the response body in the endpoint, so I'm still not sure of the benefits of a IResult derived class.

app.MapGet("/test", (HttpContext httpContext) => { ...; xdoc.SaveAsync(httpContext.Response.Body,SaveOptions.None,CancellationToken.None);});